# Java unchecked method invocation

Tags: java, sqlite, generics

I'm trying to setup a multithreaded application using SQLite4java, and everything is working fine. However, according to the getting started tutorial I am meant to create an object of type "object" and in order to return a value of null (due to use of generic types).

Here is the suggested code:

```
 queue.execute(new SQLiteJob<Object>() {
    protected Object job(SQLiteConnection connection) throws SQLiteException {
      // this method is called from database thread and passed the connection
      connection.exec(...);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/JobQueue)

The following example code I created produces the same warning:
**warning:**

```
test.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: <T,J>execute(J) in com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue is applied to (query<java.lang.Integer>)
       queue.execute(new query<Integer>());
```

**test.java:**

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.*;  
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.File;
    class test{
        
        public static  void main(String[] args){
            File f = new File("file.db");
           SQLiteQueue queue = new SQLiteQueue(f); 
           queue.execute(new query<Integer>());
        }
    
    }
```

**query.java:**

```
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteJob;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection;
import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class query<T> extends SQLiteJob{


    protected ArrayList<Integer> job(SQLiteConnection connection) throws SQLiteException{

        ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //DB Stuff
        return ints;
    }
}
```

I have read a lot about how this particular message appears when people fail to specify a type for an ArrayList. However, I am not attempting to cast the object or do anything with it. It is merely a mechanism implemented by the library developers in order to return a null. I do not believe this to be an issue relating directly to the library, which is why I'm asking this on StackOverflow.

I believe it all comes down to my lack of experience with generic types. I've already spent a few hours on this and don't feel like I am getting anywhere.

How do I stop the warning?

Comment: Post the complete and exact warning message. Post the actual code causing it, and tell us precisely which line of the code the warning refers to.

Comment: Use @SuppressWarnings('unchecked')

Comment: I have updated the first post to reflect a real world example

Comment: Don't confuse warnings and errors. They're different for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `query` class. You extend a generic class yet you don't specify the value for the generic type.

You should delcare it like this (although this has no real use...):

```
class Query<T> extends SQLiteJob<T> {
    protected T job(SQLiteConnection connection)
            throws SQLiteException{
            return ...; // Return something of type T
    }
}
```

Or if you want it to work specifically for `List<Integer>`:

```
class IntListQuery extends SQLiteJob<List<Integer>> {
    protected ArrayList<Integer> job(SQLiteConnection connection)
            throws SQLiteException{
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Populate list
        return list;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SQLiteQueue queue = new SQLiteQueue(f); 
queue.execute(new IntListQuery());
```